# How to cache Json Data for to view offline when Internet is not availaible in Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, json, android-studio

I'm using Json Data to populate my html tables and I have added these html pages inside assets folder for offline use. Inside Html File, I have included table which rows and columns is populated by Json Data.

I would like to able to cache the Json Data for Offline view when Internet is not availaible and overwrite the existing Data when new Json Data is available.

Any Solution guys?

My index.html includes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 
<div class="table-responsive">
 <h1>Json</h1>
 <br/>

 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="employee_table">
  <tr>
   <th>Class</th>
   <th>Time</th>
   
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>



<script >
 

$(document).ready(function(){
 $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/8qktd", function(data){
 var employee_data= '';
 $.each(data, function(key, value){
  employee_data += '<tr>';
  employee_data += '<td>'+value.class+'</td>';
  employee_data += '<td>'+value.time+'</td>';
  
  employee_data += '</tr>';
 });
 $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);

      });

});
</script>
```

My Json file includes

```html
[

    {
    "id":"1",    
    "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
    
},
{


    "id":"2",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{

    "id":"3",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{
    "id":"4",
    "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},
{


    "id":"5",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{

    "id":"6",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{
    "id":"7",
  "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},
{


    "id":"8",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{

    "id":"9",
   "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{
    "id":"10",
    "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},
{


    "id":"11",
    "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
},

{

    "id":"12",
    "time":"10-15",
    "class":"John Smith"
}

]
```

and my Webview includes the code,

```js
       
        mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
       WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the local storage, save each received json in local storage and when the page is loading fill the table with the local storage json. Then if the internet was connected, Fill the table with the online jason data.

To save a json file in local storage you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var employee_data= '';
  if(localStorage.myJSON !== undefined){
    var myJSON = JSON.parse(localStorage.myJSON);
    employee_data += '<tbody>';
    $.each(myJSON, function(key, value){
      employee_data += '<tr>';
      employee_data += '<td>'+value.class+'</td>';
      employee_data += '<td>'+value.time+'</td>';

      employee_data += '</tr>';
    });
    employee_data += '</tbody>';
    $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);
  }

  employee_data= '';  // empty employee_data

  $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/8qktd", function(data){
      $("#yourtableid tbody").remove();    // Empty table before filling it with new data

      localStorage.setItem(myJSON, JSON.stringify(data)); // Save new data in localStorage
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
        employee_data += '<tr>';
        employee_data += '<td>'+value.class+'</td>';
        employee_data += '<td>'+value.time+'</td>';

        employee_data += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);

  });

});
```

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback. As you have suggested, should I need to place data=localStorage.myJSON in OnCreate of Main activity then? . Most importantly , I guess solution you have provided will load the JSON file that is stored in local storage. Now By which method can I then populate the html table with Online Json Data when Internet is available ??will that overwrite the previously existed Json Data?? I'm really new to coding and everything I learned so far is from examples and youtubes...so Sorry If I have messed with anything.

Comment: First I should say this is a web approach; I'm not sure if it is applicable for mobile applications or not. I updated the code. As you see I first check if the localStorage.myJSON is undefined or not. If myJSON exists then I fill the table of the page with it. Then I send the getJSON request; If there is an internet connection, By receiving the online json data, It will empty the table and fill it with new received json data. It also saves the new data in localStorage.

Comment: I'll definitely give it a try and I'll tell you if it worked or not ( please God, make it work ). One last question, Is there any way that I add an Button inside html page and onClick It would update the Table with new Json Data and show a message Dialog Box " Table is Updated" and if Both the local storage JSON and Online JSOn are same , then Return "Your Table is UptoDate". If it could it be done, I'd be very blessed.

Comment: If the code I wrote worked then Adding the new ones you want would be easy. All you would need is to put that $.getJSON in a new function and call the function in the button onclick. And check the received answer with your local storage data to show the appropriate message.

Comment: Ok I'll look forward to it and consider I have previously stored an Json file named example.json inside same directory of index.html. so in place of localStorage.myJSON    i.e myJSOn should I replace it with example.json or example or what should I do then??

Comment: I really don't know. Check to see if it is the one you want or no, and iff you can replace it with new received json iles or not. if yes use that. As I said I am a web developer, not an Android (or iOS) developer.

Answer (score 0):

instead of directly putting retrieved data in html elements, first define variables and if json data is not null save these data to those variables if its null those variables should desplay data saved before or default data which you can set before hand.

Comment: I'm really sorry , but I'm really new to coding area, Everything I learned so far is from youtube channels and examples and slowly I'm starting to make sense....what you have said has gone over my head. I'd really appreciate and will help me If you could demonstrate what you suggested for me to do...It would be really helpful.

Comment: @Ashkan, One last Question Does the code will itself create a new file called myJSON and save it in same directory and load it from that file in future or should I first save my JSON file with name myJSON and save it in same directory?